# how to rewrite url using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to re-write below url

www.sitename.com/component/participate/1|view=participant&msg=loggedin

with

www.sitename.com/component/participate/1?view=participant&msg=loggedin

where | is replacing with ? and 1 is dynamic.

I tried :

Redirect 301 /component/competition/1|view=participant&msg=loggedin www.sitename.com/component/participate/1?view=participant&msg=loggedin

But it is working for ID 1 only. I want solution for any number the url have.

Comment: You're looking for [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) with `\d+` instead of your number.

Comment: I don't know why my question is down voted. Is anything wrong in this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this .htaccess file in your root directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^component/participate/(\d+)\|(.*)$ component/participate/$1?$2
```

$1: refers to the matched group of d+ (i.e. any number). $2: refers to anything after the "|" charater

This assumes that the "1" variable is an integer. If you want it to match other patterns you would probably need to use another regular expression pattern